# Why called CallVoidMethod throwed use of invalid jobject with JNI

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm a beginner on JNI,when I try to do this :

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_kalexjune_digitalimage_MainActivity_getBalanceMatrix(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                      jobject instance) {
    // TODO
    jclass jcs;
    jmethodID mid;
    jstring arg;
    jobject mobj;
    mobj = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env,instance);
    jcs = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,instance);
    mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,jcs,"setMatrix","(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
    if(mid!=0){
        (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env,mobj,mid,arg);

        const char * ss = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,arg,0);
        printf("from native: %s\n",ss);
    }

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "hello,i'm from native");
}
```

it's logged:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: use of invalid jobject 0x7f49b9dd2240
...
libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallMethodV(char const*, _JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*,...
lib64/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::CallVoidMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+151)    
digitalimage-1/lib/x86_64/libdigital-jni.so (Java_com_example_kalexjune_digitalimage_MainActivity_getBalanceMatrix+174)
```

My question is:

it means the param which named instance is invalid?

what could i do to fix my issue?

(forget my poor english.. :)

Comment: Your code lacks all error checking. You must check the result of *every* JNI call, and show or throw the resulting exception if you get a failure. NB You don't need to create a `GlobalRef` just to call an instance method. These are scarce resources: don't waste them.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a non-initialized `jstring` object, which could easily cause the JNI error. JNI function cannot use `jstring` as [out] parameter. Actually, `java.lang.String` parameter for any Java method is "immutable". You could rewrite your piece as

```
mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env,jcs,"setMatrix","()Ljava/lang/String;");
 
arg = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, mobj, mid);
const char *ss = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, arg, 0);
```

(and naturally this requires changes on the Java side, too).

Note that there are other problems in your code snippet: you must call ReleaseStringUTFChars(), and your `printf` output will go into void: you should use `__android_log_print()` instead.